# Getting null values on REST Resource when consuming POST in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, post

I am basically passing data with the POST request but the values on the REsource side are always null.

Here is my JQuery:

```
function doUpdate(path, rdf)
        {
            var myObj = {"path": path, "rdf": rdf};
            var sUrl = "http://localhost:8080/browsing/services/RDF/update";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: sUrl,
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: myObj,
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function parse(resp, status, xhr) {
                   $("#message").html("STATUS: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + "\n" + resp);
                   $("#message").hide();
                   $("#login_message").html("<font color='green'><b>Record succesfully updated</b></font>d");
                },
                error: function(resp, status, xhr){
                    $("#message").html("ERROR: " + resp.status + " " + resp.statusText + "\n" + xhr);
                    $("#message").show();
                }
            });
        }
```

And the REST Resource:

```
@POST
    @XmlElement(name = "contentbean")
    @Path("/update")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void update(@QueryParam("path") String Path, @QueryParam("rdf") String Content) {
        ...     

    }
```

Any clue what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

**EDIT**

Also using Poster in Firefox I see null values on the REST Resource, so independently form my Javascript code, it seems on the REST side there are some mistakes.

Comment: I doubt there is a issue in @QueryParam's. @FormParam("path") might help.

Comment: are you sure about `success: function parse(...)`... ? where did you see the `parse` part?

Comment: @Oliboy50 I've always used that to parse the response...that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

remove **dataType: "json",** and it'll work

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could read as following

```
@POST
@XmlElement(name = "contentbean")
@Path("/update")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void update(Contentbean contentbean) {

}
```

where Contentbean is a (POJO) class annotated with @XmlRootElement according to the data you send from ajax.